# No module named 'dateutil.easter' in airflow even though I have python-dateutil installed

Tags: python, selenium, airflow, importerror

Hello I'm trying to run a dag using airflow I'm getting this DAG Import Error:

```
Broken DAG: [/myCustomPath/scraping_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx", line 22, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil.easter'
```

I'm trying to test selenium in airflow any advice would be appreciated thanks! I already have python-dateutil installed in my machine. running `pip3 list` gives me:
`python-dateutil                          2.7.3`

The code is:

```
def get_header_title():
    url_web = 'https://www.google.com/search'
    driver.get(url_web)
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
        "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
    user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
    print(user_agent)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    #search_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    #    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class, "gLFyf gsfi")]')))
    # search_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class, "gLFyf gsfi")]')
    #time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
    print("we've crossed the element")
    search_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@title, 'Search')]")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    try:
        search_field.click()
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        print(" error clicking search")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    search_field.send_keys("astronaut")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    search_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(0.75)
    title = driver.title
    print(title)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}

with DAG(
    'selenium_test',
    default_args=default_args,
    description = 'Selenium test DAG',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['selenuium_test']
) as dag:

    selenium_test_operator = PythonOperator(
         task_id='selenium_test',
         python_callable=get_header_title,
         dag=dag
    )
```

Comment: Please share share your code, not only the error traceback

Comment: I updated with the code @Prophet

Comment: how are you running airflow on your system? is it local install or through Kubernetes or docker-compose? 
if its using K8 or docker, dateutil should be present inside the worker pod/container.